# do try catch swift 2

Tags: swift2, do-catch

HI i am a little confused about how to transfer if_else error handling to do try catch successfully.

Here is my code.

```
let error : NSError?
if(managedObjectContext!.save()) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("updateUndoState", object: nil)    
    if error != nil {
       print(error?.localizedDescription)
    }
}
else {
    print("abort")
    abort()
}
```

and now i converted to swift 2.0 like this

```
do {
   try managedObjectContext!.save()
}
catch {
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("updateUndoState", object: nil)
     print((error as NSError).localizedDescription)
}
```

I am confused about where to print abort and do the abort() function

Any idea~? Thanks a lot

Comment: In your original code, where does `error` come from? It is not coming from `save()`.

Comment: @Sulthan thanks for ur remind. However after changing my code, it occurs that : Variable 'error' used before being initialized

Comment: @Sulthan - No, the `error` _is_ thrown by the `save()`. When you have `catch` without a `let`, it automatically uses `error` as a reference to the thrown error.

Comment: @Rob I was speaking about the `error` in the first example.

Comment: Ok. That first example was obviously a typo because it isn't valid Swift 1.2 code. So I assumed you must have meant the second code snippet. But you're right that that first code snippet is missing the error reference in the `save()` call.

Comment: The original Swift 1 code wouldn't work in the first place. The error would never be logged. That's why I assumed the `error` variable contains a different error.

Comment: Lol. Yeah, because Swift 1.2 code is missing a required `error` parameter to `save`, I assumed that was the root of the typo. Regardless, the first code snippet is (still) not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting your code to work the same as your original code

```
do {
   try managedObjectContext!.save()

   //this happens when save did pass
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("updateUndoState", object: nil)    

   //this error variable has nothing to do with save in your original code
   if error != nil {
       print(error?.localizedDescription)
   }
}
catch {
   //this happens when save() doesn't pass
   abort()
}
```

what you probably want to write is the following:

```
do {
   try managedObjectContext!.save()

   //this happens when save did pass
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("updateUndoState", object: nil)    
}
catch let saveError as NSError {
   //this happens when save() doesn't pass
   print(saveError.localizedDescription)
   abort()
}
```

Comment: I now understand your first code snippet. You assumed that he had some other `error` variable floating around. His revised question makes it clear that this is not the case, but I now get why you wrote what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Everything within `do {}` is good, everything within `catch {}` is bad

```
do {
   try managedObjectContext!.save()
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("updateUndoState", object: nil)
}
catch let error as NSError {
     print(error.localizedDescription)
     abort()
}
```

use either the error handling or the abort() statement